# "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" after adding "return"

Tags: express, http-post, express-router

So I have a router to post data and it gives an error `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`. I reviewed previously asked questions about the same error and all of them suggesting to put `return` in front of `response`. But in my situation, it is already the case.

This is the router in `blogs.js` that gives the error:

```
blogRouter.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    const token = req.token;
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
    if ((!token || !decodedToken)) {
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'unauthorized: token missing or invalid' });
        return;
    } else if (!body.title || !body.url) {
        res.status(400).json({error: 'Missing data'});
        return;
    }
    const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id);
    const blog = new Blog({
        title: body.title,
        author: body.author,
        url: body.url,
        user: user._id,
        likes: body.likes ? body.likes : 0
    });
  
    const result = await blog.save();
    user.blogs = user.blogs.concat(blog);
    await user.save();
    return res.status(201).json(result);
});
```

My error handler middleware is throwing `HTTP 404`. I have checked the endpoint both in the request and in the middleware.

[This](https://github.com/rd9911/UniHelsinkiFullStack/blob/main/part4/utils/middleware.js) is my middleware if that can help

What is causing the issue here? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured that our. In my middleware where I extract token I had:

```
const tokenExtractor = (req, res, next) => {
    const authorization = req.get('authorization');
    console.log(authorization);
    if (authorization && authorization.toLowerCase().startsWith('bearer ')) {
        req.token = authorization.substring(7);
        next() // remove this!
    }
    next();  
};
```

`next()` should not have been called for two times but only when given task (in this case if block of my code) would not have resolved. So I removed `next()` in my if block as it resolves the task.

Next time, I will do better debugging before posting it there.